# Windows 10 1909 start menu side-bar behavior

Tags: windows-10

I'm currently using Windows 10 1903 and it is the first Windows 10 version I'm using as my primary OS.

I've tried 1909 (18363.418) already and noticed that when I hover the cursor over the side-bar on the left of the Windows Start Menu, the side-bar expands to its full size instead of just showing the tooltip for the hovered item like in 1903.

[image: Windows 10 Start Menu side-bar default mouse over behavior]

In 1903 there is the standard three-stripes icon on the top for ones who not satisfied with tooltips and want to expand the Start Menu side-bar.

In 1909's Start Menu this icon also exists and expands the side-bar to its full size, as expected.

The problem is hovering the mouse over the 1909's Start Menu side-bar also expands the side-bar to its full size instead of just showing the tooltip for the hovered side-bar item.

I've searched several times through the whole Settings app but haven't found how to get rid of this annoying behavior.

May be I can change something in the registry?

Comment: I have been using Windows 10 for nearly 5 years and the very left side bar is always collapsed by default. Please  show us a screen shot of what you see. V1909 is not out yet except Insider. I have both V1903 and 19H2 (to be V1909) here and the Start Menu behaves exactly the same way on both. No difference. The 3 bars expand the very left to show Name, Documents, Pictures, Settings the same way on both versions. 19H2 (to be 1909) may change when it is released.

Comment: I didn't understand from your comment if your 1903's side-bar expands to its full by just hovering the mouse pointer over it, or shows the tooltips for hovered items. I have updated my question with the screenshots anyway.

Comment: Hovering with my mouse does not expand the side-bar as you show in V1903 and Insider 19H2 (to be V1909).  On both versions, it is necessary to click on the 3 bars.  1909 is not out yet (except on Insider machines) but it does not seem to change anything.  Have you installed some third party menu system?

Comment: I have clean-installed RTM 1909 from MSDN channel. The same as the one that is going to be released to public. No, I have not installed any 3rd party menu. With some research I have discovered that my situation is the default side-bar behavior for 1909's Start Menu. So be prepared. But if you are sure your 1909 side-bar doesn't expand on hovering with the mouse pointer and in case you've got 1909 via upgrading your existing 1903, there is the chance the side-bar's behavior could be configured via the registry.

Comment: Please see Start, Settings, Systems, About. The most recent production version is 1903  18362.449.  The most recent about to be released version is 1903  19013.1 . There is no release yet of V1909. Neither version responds to mouse hovering over the far left side-bar. Nor has any prior version so far as I recall. I do not ever use the Registry as a user tool. Might you have done such?  Because none of my own 3 machines do this, nor several client machines yesterday.

Comment: As I have already told expanding side-bar with mouse over is now **standard behaviour**, since 1909. It absolutely doesn't matter if 1909 released already or still yet to be released. There is the final version already, I have it clean-installed, with all available updates applied immediately. It is great you have no such problem, and I suspect it is only because you have updated your previous Windows 10 to 1909 and 1909 is just using your previous settings. That means I will solve my problem as soon as I knew where to find those settings and how to adjust them. Please do not answer further.

Comment: New version of 1903 (to be 1909) this morning and yes, the behavior has indeed changed. That is new with this build (19013.1) and just something to adapt to. It is closed unless you open it or hover over it, so no issue for me at this point, but it is the result of a very new version

Comment: *the side-bar expands to its full size instead of just showing the tooltip for the hovered item like in 1903*... hovering in 1903 also expands the menu bar. This is not new for 1909.

Comment: This only proves there should be setting to customize this behavior.

Comment: The hovering behaviour was announced on [windowslatest.com](https://www.windowslatest.com/2018/11/15/windows-10-19h1-to-change-start-menus-navigation-pane-behaviour/). They consider it as an _improvement_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix such behaviour:

1. Download the **mach2 tool** from [its official GitHub page](https://github.com/riverar/mach2/releases)
2. Extract the ZIP archive to any folder you want
3. Open a new command prompt as Administrator. Go to the folder that contains your copy of the mach2 tool. E.g. by typing *cd /d c:\mach2*
4. Type the following command: *mach2 disable 18715789*
5. Restart your computer

The solution is taken from this blog post: https://winaero.com/blog/disable-start-menu-auto-expand-on-mouse-over-in-windows-10/

Comment: While I prefer this feature is a part of standard Windows settings, using 3rd party tool is anyway better than nothing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just installed Windows 10, Version 2004, and now mach2 no longer works. Did the ID 18715789 change? Is there another way of disabling auto expand?